# Terminal: I can't type anything

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, gnome-terminal

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and I was trying to download updates but my machine glitched, I couldn't do anything, waited for a few minutes, and then had to force off the machine by holding down the power button. After switching it on I noticed I couldn't type commands on my terminal.

I haven't updated anything in the past few days. The update that was running was from the software update Ubuntu application, so it was probably updating stuff in the system that required an update. when I open the terminal, the first thing I see is the cursor blinking, It doesn't show the folder I am in or my username as it used it, and I cannot type in the terminal, not even a letter.

Please tell me how do I fix this issue.

This is my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"


# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

Comment: "*After switching it on I noticed I couldn't type commands on my terminal. Please tell me how do I fix this issue.*" ... You, please tell us more information ... What commands exactly did you run before powering off? Why/how you couldn't type commands? What commands exactly? How are you doing that? What do you see? What do you expect? ... etc. ... **and** what did you change/update on your system further in the past days? are manual Python updates involved?

Comment: I haven't updated anything in the past few days. The update that was running was from the software update Ubuntu application, so it was probably updating stuff in the system that required an update. when I open the terminal, the first thing I see is the cursor blinking, It doesn't show the folder I am in or my username as it used it, and I cannot type in the terminal, not even a letter

Comment: can you please show us the contents of the `~/.bashrc` file. (it's a hidden file under your home directory) please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Do you have to login or is that automatic?  Sounds like the keyboard isn't being picked up?

Comment: @Raffa I have added my .bashrc file to the question

Comment: @Mike I don't think it's a keyboard issue because I can still type on other applications

Comment: Rename it to `old.bashrc` then close and reopen your terminal and see if it works.

Comment: @Raffa I renamed it and it works fine now, thanks. but what might be the issue on my bashrc file?

Comment: Well done, I'll try to explain in more details in an answer in a moment as comments are limited in character number and formatting.

Comment: You should become familiar with the *Magic SysRq key* and how to use it to avoid cutting the power to a "frozen" system (it can be bad for the filesystems). You might need to enable functionality using /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq . And learn the ctrl-alt-F# virtual terminals, if your gui was frozen you might be able to switch to another terminal and login & kill processes yourself (possibly using the SysRq R key to first get the keyboard listening). Linux rarely completely crashes. Sometimes just waiting 5-30m could let the oom killer activate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a common issue usually resulting from modifying/customizing your `~/.bashrc` file. It's a hidden file under your home directory. It's sourced by default in an interactive Bash shell the first thing when it's started i.e. when you open the terminal.

My first suggestion is to rename that file to something else like `old.bashrc` for example and reopen the terminal to see if it works as normally expected again. If that was the case then you know what the culprit is and you can start debugging your `.bashrc` (Start by commenting out all those `source` and `.` commands) to see which part/command is causing this and fix it before you can use that file again if you want to.

There is nothing odd or wrong in customizing `.bashrc` but as you have just discovered, it can cause issues if it's not well maintained ... There are some bad practices (*could be*) in your `.bashrc` file like for example running `eval` on the output of a command substitution `eval "$(...)"`and sourcing the output of a process substitution `source <(...)` ... Those are considered bad practices as the output of both could change e.g. when those commands versions get upgraded and the new versions produce unexpected output.

You also appear to be sourcing many other files/scripts which there is, again, nothing wrong with it unless those files as well have similar bad practices.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Can I get a standard bashrc file from you as you have mentioned above?

Comment: @Zoms Sure, it's under `/etc/skel` in every Ubuntu system ... That's what gets copied when a user is created. So, just copy it `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` and you're good to go.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much

Comment: There's several files that could be sourced when bash starts, they're in the INVOCATION section of bash's man page. Stuff like /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, or for *interactive login shells* /etc/profile, and one of ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile. If renaming ~/.bashrc didn't work, trying to rename another might